# Formal definition of stable sorting algorithm

Tags: sorting

Suppose $a$ is an array and $cmp$ is a "compare function" that is a function which outputs $true / false$ values. I say that an algorithm $A$ which takes in input $a$ and $cmp$ is a stable sorting algorithm if $b=A(a,cmp)$ satisfies the following conditions:

*Sorting conditions:*

1) exist a permutation $p$ such that $a \circ p= b$ ($\circ$ is composition)

2) $\forall i<j \to cmp(b[j],b[i])=false$

*Condition of stability:*

3) $\forall i<j$ $cmp(b[j],b[i])=false \to p[i]<p[j]$

In substance: cmp() is only a boolean function like in STL library C++ it takes two elements a,b and $cmp(a,b) \in \{true, false\}$ while $p$ is bijective function on {1,...,length(a)}

Further, I have two claims.

1) Exist and there could be many $b$ whose satisfy 1-2. So, any sorting anlgorithm (not necessarly stable) $A$ gives me a particular $b$.

2) Exist and is unique $b$ who satisfies 1-2-3.

Are my conditions and claims correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are two major issues I see:

- cmp() is not formally defined, so it could be anything, meaning that b isn't necessarily a sorted version of a.
- p is not formally defined either.

So I'd say that neither your conditions, nor your claims derived from those conditions are correct. But, if you'd fix your definitions, I think your claims would follow from it.

Comment: cmp() is only a boolean function like in STL library C++. p is bijective function on {1,...,length(a)}.

Comment: Can you give me your definition?

Comment: Are you asking for a formal definition or are you asking for a validation of yours? These are two different questions.

Comment: p being a bijective function needs to be part of your formal definition. Also, for cmp, you need to define its behavior. The only thing clear in your definition is that it can return false. But does it return true? In what conditions? If cmp(a,b)=false, what is cmb(b,a)? These are the things you need to cover if you want to have a formal definition.

Comment: I made an update after the three sorting conditions.